# CSS not showing in Internet Exploer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, nav

I've been working on a project in HTML and CSS,but IE doesn't show any of my styling. 
I'm not sure why my nav is not showing - it just displays as a simple list. 
Some help would be greatly appreciated!

My CSS is an external style sheet:

```
 <style>

    header {
    background: url(milo.png);
    background-position:center;
    border-radius: 15px 50px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top:1em;
    height: 140px;
    width: 140px;
    border:2px dotted;
    padding: 30px;
 }

h1 {    font-family: "Courier New";
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:24px;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 40px;}

div {
    background-color:#8B7C9D;
    padding:1em; }  

body{
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Helvetica Nueue", Arial, sans-serif;
}
nav {
    background-color: #333;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align:center;
}
nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;

}
nav ul li {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

nav > ul > li > a {
    color: #aaa;
    display: block;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0.5em 2em;
    text-decoration: none;

}

nav li > ul{
    display : none;
    margin-top:1px;
    background-color: #bbb;

}

nav li > ul li{
    display: block;
    text-align:left;
}

nav  li > ul li a {
    color: #111;
    display: block;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0.5em 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav li:hover {
    background-color: #C4C4C4;
}
nav li:hover > ul{
    position:absolute;
    display : block;
}


nav ul > li.sub{
    background: url(Arrow.png) right center no-repeat;
}


</style>
```

Apologies, I'm quite new to the whole stackoverflow crew. 
Heres the JSFiddle Link :) https://jsfiddle.net/jskk00ch/

Comment: Why do you use script tags in an external style sheet?

Comment: Does it work when you add `type="text/css"` to the `<style>` tag?

Comment: Which version of IE/Edge? What does [W3C/jigsaw validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/) says? +1 for HTML file or better a fiddle/codepen reproducing your problem

Comment: I've not used the external style sheet method before, should I remove the style tags?

Comment: @LuudJacobs sadly not

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Internet Explorer doesn't allow a  tag inside a  tag. When I use this HTML in IE:

```
<nav><ul><li>test</li></ul></nav>
```

IE's DOM Explorer shows it as:

```
<nav></nav>
<ul><li>test</li></ul>
</nav><//nav>
```

The styles aren't getting applied because the ul tag is no longer inside the nav tag.

Comment: Are you referring to IE8- without html5shiv or IE11/Edge? I highly doubt it happens in the latter ;)

Comment: Sorry, i'm just a little confused. So your advice is i take away the nav tags?

Comment: It happens in IE11. I haven't tried Edge. I'm not sure what the best solution is here.